# Are all right inverses of a given function, injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Suppose we have a function P, I want to show that all right-inverses of P are injective. I know that if a function has a left-inverse, then it bound to be injective. Isn't it correct that all right-inverses of P have P as left-inverse, thus are injective?

Comment: Let's say $g$ is a right inverse of $P$, which means $P\circ g=id$. Now suppose $g(x)=g(y)$. Can you conclude that $x=y$ from this?

Comment: The answer to your question seems to be no, but I don't get what is wrong in my assessment.

Comment: Hit that on the left with $P$.

Answer (score 1):

You have exactly the right idea! You simply need to formalize it.

Suppose that $P$ is a function and that $g$ is a right inverse of $P$. Suppose now that $x,y$ are elements of the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)=g(y).$ To show that $g$ is injective, we must show that $x=y.$ The only properties we haven't yet used is the right inverse property and the definition of functions. Since $P\circ g$ is well-defined, then $g(x)=g(y)$ is an element of the domain of $P.$ Thus, since $P$ is a function and $g(x)=g(y),$ then $$P\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=P\bigl(g(y)\bigr),$$ meaning $$(P\circ g)(x)=(P\circ g)(y).$$ What do you know about $P\circ g$ that can get you the rest of the way?

Answer (score 0):

This results from general result on sets:

> Let  $X,Y,Z\;$ be sets and $f:X\longrightarrow Y, \;g:Y\longrightarrow Z\;$ two maps. Then:
>
> 1. If $\;g\circ f$ is injective, $f$ is injective.
> 2. If $\;g\circ f$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective.

Proofs thereof by contrapositive.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to my question.

Comment: What properties does the identity have?